# Trying to read keychain data when updating an old Cordova app with a new React Native application

Tags: android, react-native, cordova

We are developing a mobile app in React Native, which should be published in App Store and Play store, as an update to existing application, which was written using Cordova.

We have the source code Cordova application as well, but we are not the actual developers of the old app.
New react native app is supposed to update the old Cordova app, without any existing data loss. (the data stored on KeyStore (Android) and Keychain (iOS) and it must reuse these data.)

When the old app is updated test devices, we tried using the below plugins to read the Keychain data from old app  -

1.react-native-keychain
2.react-native-secure-key-store
3.react-native-sensitive-info
4.AsyncStorage from React native

and try to fetch the data, but with no success. We tried achieving this on Android app first.

For all the plguns except "react-native-keychain", we were unable to get the keychain data itself, as it was returning null.

"react-native-keychain" -  is not having any method to read the keychain data as key-value pair, hence not able to proceed further.

Any guidance on how to proceed in achieving this would be of great help.

Regards
SBK

Comment: What plugin does the old app use?